# Concurrent update MySQL vs PostgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, postgresql, innodb

We have just migrated from MySQL to PostgreSQL, a particular row for every minute will be heavily updated. All those period when the product was running in MySQL we had no issues, but when after moving to PostgreSQL we faced so many deadlocks.

Table structure.

```
Create table tab(col1 int , col2 int , col3 int, PRIMARY KEY(col1));
```

No index.

Deadlock query -

```
Update tab set col2=col2+1 where col3=xx;
```

(yes, there will be more than one row for result).

My question: How has MySQL handled this situation to avoid deadlocks ? (Asking this question assuming that the problem in PostgreSQL with regard to this query is because of getting the rows in different order every time a concurrent update is happening).

I might have faced deadlocks in MySQL also, but definitely it was not to the extent of how it happened with PostgreSQL.

And I have already gone through the question posted in https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151813/why-can-mysql-handle-multiple-updates-concurrently-and-postgresql-cant
the answer posted here was not very convincing as the author went all about complaining the update architecture of PostgreSQL and HOT updates.

I want to know the difference in architecture that enabled MySQL to avoid this problem.

Comment: I'm not sure this is appropriate to stack overflow either as the questions here are more concrete application solving issues not 'how does this application do this'...as mysql is open source I would consult the mysql developer community

Comment: Unsure why you're getting downvotes, this is pretty sensible.

Comment: See here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/151813/1822 for an extended discussion

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, MySQL (presumably with InnoDB tables) is probably doing the updates in a consistent order each time, while PostgreSQL's access is generally unordered.  This makes sense, given that InnoDB uses index-organized tables while PostgreSQL uses heaps.

PostgreSQL unfortunately does not support `UPDATE ... ORDER BY`. You can take a row-lock before you `UPDATE` to ensure reliable ordering at the cost of an extra round-trip, e.g.

```
BEGIN;
SELECT 1 FROM tab WHERE col3 = xx FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE tab SET col2=col2+1 WHERE col3=xx;
COMMIT;
```

(I'd love to have `UPDATE ... ORDER BY` support in PostgreSQL. Patches welcome!)

Comment: I agree. It's probably to do with the fact that InnoDB tables are always a clustered index.